# How do you do an alert / message / popup box using JScript on Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-10, jscript, wsh

I'm trying to do a Window `alert` on **Windows 10** and it's not going so well.

This is what I tried:

```js
window.alert("Alert");
```

And

```js
alert("Alert");
```

It doesn't matter if its in another language too. But if there is a way to do it in JavaScript, please answer!

Comment: alert("Alert"); should work.

You can test it out here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert

I just did, on win 10 and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.alert` is the browser function only. You can execute it in browser environment only.

For simple message box in WSH JScript write:

```js
WScript.Echo("Windows message box sample");
```

If you need extended message box in WSH JScript write:

```js
var mbOK = 0,
    mbOKCancel = 1,
    mbCancel = 2,
    mbInformation = 64, // Information icon
    text  = //"Windows Script Host sample",
    title = //"Title sample",
    wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"),
    intDoIt =  wshShell.Popup(text,
                    0, //if > 0, seconds to show popup. With 0 it is without timeout.
                    title,
                    mbOKCancel + mbInformation);
if(intDoIt == mbCancel) 
{
    WScript.Quit(); //End of WScript (every for & while loops end too)
}

WScript.Echo("Sample executed");
```

You have to save all it in `example.js` file and execute this file with mouse double click. If you need **support for internationale messages** then save it in **unicode** format (but **NOT** in UTF-8 format!).

### Some useful exended example

If you need some message box every 15 seconds (or maybe 1 hour) you can do it with `while` loop and `WScript.sleep` function, because we don't have `setTimeout` function in WSH JScript too.

In the next code sample we have a message box every 15 seconds in endless loop if you click all the time on OK button. A click on cancel button will end the full script (every for & while loops end too).

```js
while(true)
{
    var mbOK = 0,
        mbOKCancel = 1,
        mbCancel = 2,
        mbInformation = 64, // Information icon
        text  = "TO-DO: Write your App code! Do It! Just Do It!",
        title = "Simple TO-DO thing",
        wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"),
        intDoIt =  wshShell.Popup(text,
                        0, //if > 0, seconds to show popup. With 0 it is without timeout.
                        title,
                        mbOKCancel + mbInformation);
    if(intDoIt == mbCancel) 
    {
        WScript.Quit(); //End of WScript (every for & while loops end too)
    }

    WScript.sleep(15000); //Every 15 seconds. And 60*60*1000=3600000 for every hour
}
```

More information you will get in [**Microsoft Windows Script Host 2.0 Developer's Guide**](http://wsh2.uw.hu/index.html) online book.

Answer (score 0):

`alert("Alert");` should work.

You can test it out here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert

I just did, on win 10 and it works fine.

Comment: Also i mean On Windows, not on the browser.

Comment: @Herter, see my answer. Your code works in browser environment only. But OP needs it in WSH JScript. You could delete your answer because it is wrong.